# Adjective for a person who deeply understands and appreciates another (really gets them)

Tags: adjectives

Instead of saying "she is the kind of person that really gets other, she really understands them deeply", I want an adjective for that.  It's not empathetic.

Comment: "Empath" is a noun which means something different entirely. "Empathic" or "empathetic" are adjectives however that do seem to fit your description very well. Also look at "sympathetic," "compassionate," "commiserative," or simply "understanding."

Comment: got to be a duplicate ... somewhere.  A very freq asked question

Comment: *Why* is it not empathetic? What are your criteria for an acceptable answer? How would you use it in a sentence?

Comment: Let's say Mary deeply understands X.  Then: Mary is on the same wavelength [with X].  Mary is really tuned into X.  X feels that Mary is a kindred spirit.  Mary and X are kindred spirits.  Mary identifies with X.  Mary is connected to X.  Mary is X's soul sister.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you said that it’s not empathetic, I think that what you’re looking for might be:

**[Empathetic](https://www.google.it/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/empathetic)**
Someone who has the ability to understand and  share someone’s feelings and emotions.

**[Understanding](https://www.google.it/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/understanding)**
Someone who is aware of someone’s condition, is tolerant and doesn’t judge.

**[Sympathetic](https://www.google.it/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/sympathetic)**
Someone who is concerned about somebody and cares about them and what they feel.

**[Supportive](https://www.google.it/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/supportive)**
Someone who understands somebody, helps and encourages them.